# Plot map of points spread into grid sub-samples

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis, ggmap

I'm trying to generate a map that looks like this in R:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTViM.png]

The boxes represent individual observations, while the colors represent data pertaining to those individual observations. Anyone have any idea how this might be accomplished?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be any "standard" plot format. R does have functions for plotting maps and for plotting boxes, but as far as arranging them in this particular configuration, there's nothing automated to my knowledge. This would require a high degree of customization.

Comment: Thanks -The R package [Direct Labels](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/) does a pretty good job figuring out how best to place text. There might be some potential methods within that package for something like this.

 I will probably create an SVG and color the boxes using css. I may need to generate a lot of these images, but layout of boxes will always be the same.